# Is nested pair a good idea in Haskell

Tags: haskell, gadt

AFAIK there is no way to do heterogeneous arrays in Haskell or extend data type.
 However it seems it could be achieved easily by using nested pair (like CONS are).

For example

```
data Point2D a = Point2D a a
data Point3D a = Point3D a a a
```

Could be written using nested pair like this;

```
type Point2D = (a, (a, ())
type Point3D = (a, (a, (a, ()))
```

That way accessors can be common for Point2D and Point3D

```
x = fst
y = fst.snd
z = fst.snd.snd
```

This technique can also be used to **extend** record like this

```
type Person = (String, ())
name = fst
type User = (String, (String, ())
email = fst.snd
```

etc ...

Is it a good idea and if so , why is there no built-in support for such thing in Haskell ?
Is it what GADT is about ?

Comment: `z = fst.snd.snd` --- not really.

Comment: @n.m `Point3D` should be `(a, (a, (a, ())`. Fixed

Comment: You still couldn't put Point2D and Point3D into one list, because () never unifies with (a, ())

Comment: Please give a concrete example of why you would need this.  I think we'll find you're almost certainly better off with some other approach.

Comment: @Ingo That's a fair point and maybe PointND is a bad example. I just want to be able to write some code which will work for both type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be a good idea, if that's what you need.

GADTs are not directly to do with this idea (if you want to know more about GADTs, probably better to google GADTs and read some of the links, and/or ask a separate Stackoverflow question).

There's no built in support for the same reason there's no built in support for graphics, matrix operations, or most other things; there's no need for support to be built in, because it can be added perfectly well by libraries, such as the [HList package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) (indeed, even most of the functionality that *is* "built in" to Haskell is actually merely implemented in libraries; just libraries that happen to be always distributed with Haskell).

HList has fancy types for representing "heterogenous lists" and convenient functions for performing operations on them, and also uses these to develop "extensible records". HLists basically are equivalent to what you could do by developing your nested tuple idea further, so your basic idea is good enough that someone's already thought of it. :)

Comment: my GADT was just a comment, not the real question. About build-in, it's more than the syntax of nested tuples seems a bit heavy, so it would benefit for syntaxic sugar if it was meant to be use heavily

Comment: @mb14 That's why someone wrote a library to provide convenient pred-defined operations (and why it doesn't actually use nested tuples). :) The whole point is "hey, Haskell's features are sufficient for this to be possible; now let's build a library around making it practical".

Comment: I had a quick look a HList and it says it depends on 'template-haskell' meaning HList is not pure haskell.

Comment: @mb14 template haskell is pure haskell, it's just not haskell98. The use of template haskell is not always considered type safe, but in 99% of cases it's fine. The lens library makes heavy use of TH and it's one of the more popular libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to have arbitrarily nested pairs:

```
data Y f = In (f (Y f))
data P a = Pair Int a | STOP
type PY = Y P

a, b :: PY
a = In (Pair 23 (In (Pair 24 (In STOP))))
b = In (Pair 23 (In (Pair 24 (In (Pair 25 (In STOP))))))    
c = [a,b]   -- a and b have same type
```